# How to animate the line drawing of CGContext inside a MKMapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm using a `MKPolyline` to draw a line between 2 `CLLocation` points in a `MKMapView`.

I want the line drawing animated - "build up" - from point A to point B. (Like the way of the walk the user did from A to B). Currently the line is just presented instantly.

[image]

I want the line from point A to point B not to appear instantly, but build up from point A to point B with an animation "fill up".

My current research brought me to the function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if overlay is MKPolyline {

        let polylineRenderer = MyRenderer(overlay: overlay)

        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.green
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 1

        // HERE

        return polylineRenderer

    } else {

        return MKOverlayRenderer()

    }

}
```

I believe the way to get to my desired animation is through the `MKOverlayRenderer`.

My current basic subclass:

```
class MyRenderer: MKPolylineRenderer {

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {

        context.saveGState()

        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.exclusion)

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)

        context.setLineWidth(10.0)

        if self.polyline.pointCount > 1 {

            context.beginPath()

            let point_ = self.point(for: self.polyline.points()[0])

            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: point_.x, y: point_.y))

            for element in 1 ..< self.polyline.pointCount {

                let point_ = self.point(for: polyline.points()[element])

                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point_.x, y: point_.y))

            }

            context.closePath()

            context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

        }

        context.restoreGState()

    }

}
```

The lines are drawn as `CGContext` from point to point. I've tried to add a sub-layer to animate this one and set the lines itself with clear color, but I haven't been able to find a view element to add a sub-layer.

What am I missing or what is the best approach to "draw" a line from one `CLLocation` point to a second `CLLocation` by `UIView.animate` (f.e.) with 0.3 seconds time.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Hi David, Did you find some Solution?

Comment: Well. There are two options. Either you animate something yourself using Core Animation. But that is very time consuming and even with me investing several days, the result was not super awesome. And the best solution is to go with MapBox framework as they have this feature on board.